# How to integrate biblatex-chicago into this "awesome-cv" template?

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago, awesome-cv

I am using the "awesome-cv" template from [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv) (which, judging by all the questions for how to modify/expand it, seems to have some issues). I want to add a bibliography to the included cover letter template, so that I can provide proper references in the cover letter with a list of references at the end; further, I would like to be able to cite my own published writing in the CV portion and have them properly formatted as bibliography entries.

However, unlike my own documents, when I add the following lines in the preamble to the cover-letter (for example):

```
\usepackage[authordate,natbib,backend=biber,alldates=iso,idemtracker=context,ibidtracker=context,dateabbrev=false,language=english,useprefix,eventdate=comp,parentracker=true]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{/path/to/bibtex/file/bookbib.bib}
```

I get errors about biber and biblatex being incompatible. What do I need to do to fix this so it works properly?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce an error with those lines. Here is what I did. I downloaded the `.zip` for `awesome-cv` from https://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv. In unpacked the files into a new, empty folder and opened `resume_cv.tex`. I added `\usepackage[authordate,natbib,backend=biber,alldates=iso,idemtracker=context,ibidtracker=context,dateabbrev=false,language=english,useprefix,eventdate=comp,parentracker=true]{biblatex-chicago}` and `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` to the preamble. ...

Comment: ... Then I added `\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}\printbibliography` just before `\end{document}` in the document body. I compiled with XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX. There were no errors and I get a bibliography in the output.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you did? Can you share an example document of what you tried to run? Can you quote the error messages you got?

Comment: OK. I made a copy of the cover_letter.tex file, called cover_letter-bibtest.tex. I added those two lines directly below the `\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else` line in the preamble.

When I compile, I get the following error:

Comment: `INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'cover_letter-bibtest.blg'
INFO - Reading 'cover_letter-bibtest.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.10.
This means that your biber (2.19) and biblatex (3.16) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1
`
I do not get this error when compiling other documents using this same bibtlatex-chicago definition, so I'm unsure what the cause is.

The only additions I made to awesome-cv.cls was to add polyglossia for language switching.

Comment: Delete the temporary files with file extension `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf` and `.blg`. Then try to compile again. Does Biber still complain about the wrong `biblatex control file version`?

Comment: yes. Same error message about biber and biblatex being incompatible

Comment: Hrm. *however*, if I change the line at the very top to read `%!TEX TS-program = lualatex` instead, it *does* compile, and print the bibliography at the end. Now I just need to figure out how to fix the font for the bitations and biblography (it's still using its own sans-serif font, which is ugly, rather than Libertinus like for the rest of the document).

Comment: That would suggest that you have several (competing) TeX systems installed on your system. Maybe look into that. Make sure that you have one system installed that is reasonably up to date.

Comment: it may very well be. Since I've been using lualatex for years, I have that defined to point to my texlive installation, while xelatex might have defaulted to the (somewhat older) system installation. Anyway, it seems solved now. I fixed the font by commenting out the sourcesanspro package in the .cls file, so now everything is as it should be. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no problem using `biblatex-chicago` with the shown template.

In this case there was an installation issue that caused problems.

---

The error message

```
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.10.
        This means that your biber (2.19) and biblatex (3.16) versions are incompatible.
        See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
```

the OP got can be read at face value. For some reason the `biblatex` version that was used when the document is compiled with LaTeX is incompatible with the Biber version. Specifically, the `biblatex` version that is being used is outdated.

Usually this happens if the TeX system was not properly updated or if certain packages were installed manually.

---

In this case the problem appears to have been the presence of multiple TeX systems in various states of completeness.

The template requests XeLaTeX compilation via magic commands in the `.tex` file. Apparently this triggered a XeLaTeX from the older installation, whereas the subsequent Biber run was from a newer installation. The OP solved the issue by switching compilation to LuaLaTeX, which apparently also comes from the newer system.

Unless you have a good reason to maintain several TeX systems (of which there are many), I suggest you make sure you only have one complete TeX system installed that is kept reasonably up to date. If you need several TeX systems, configure them in such a way that they don't interfere with each other.